# Central extension of a Lie algebra, why is the bilinear form a 2-cocycle?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology, central-extensions

My professor talked about a central extension of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, which he defined as $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}=\mathfrak g\oplus\mathbb C$. The Lie bracket on $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}$ is

$$\widetilde{[a,b]}=[a,b]+k\eta(a,b)$$

where $k$ is the base vector of $\mathbb C$ and $\eta:\mathfrak g\oplus\mathfrak g\to\mathbb C$ a bilinear form.

For $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}$ to be a Lie algebra, $\eta$ must be asymmetric. Furthermore, because of the Jacobi identity of $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}$, $\eta$ must satisfy

$$\tag{1}\eta([a,b],c)+\eta([b,c],a)+\eta([c,a],b)=0$$

for all $a,b,c\in\mathfrak g$.

Then he mentioned that these requirements are exactly those that make $\eta$ a 2-cocycle of $\mathfrak g$.

To my knowledge, a 2-cocycle of $\mathfrak g$ is defined as an asymmetric bilinear form $\eta$ on $\mathfrak g$ that satisfies $\mathrm{d}\eta=0$, i.e.

\begin{align}
0 & = \mathrm{d}\eta(a,b,c) \\
\tag{2}&= \underbrace{-\eta(a,b)-\eta(b,c)-\eta(c,a)}_{(*)}+\eta([a,b],c)+\eta([b,c],a)+\eta([c,a],b)
\end{align}

Why is $(1)$ the same as $(2)$? In other words, why do the first three terms $(*)$ in $(2)$ vanish?

**EDIT:** I think I understand the argument by @TsemoAristide, but I wanted to write it out explicitly to see why I was wrong exactly.

The Lie algebra $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}$ has to satisfy the Jacobi identity, so we get

\begin{align}
0 &= \widetilde{[a,\widetilde{[b,c]}]} + (\text{even permutations})\\
&= \widetilde{[a, [b,c]]}+\widetilde{[a,k\eta(b,c)]}+(\text{p.})\\
&= \underbrace{[a,[b,c]]}_{\text{Jacobi-Identity of }\mathfrak{g}}+k\eta(a,[b,c])+\underbrace{k[a,\eta(b,c)]}_{=0\text{ since }\eta(b,c)\text{ is in }\mathbb C}+\underbrace{k^2}_{=k}\eta(a,\eta(b,c))+(\text{p.})\\
&= k(\eta(a,[b,c])+\eta(a,\eta(b,c))+(\text{p.}))\\
\end{align}

From that we can conclude that

\begin{align}
\tag{3} 0 &= \eta(a,[b,c])+\eta(a,\eta(b,c))+(\text{p.})\\
\end{align}

Is that correct so far?

So we indeed get more terms than just $(1)$. However, $(3)$ is still not the same as $(2)$. What's wrong?

Comment: No, 2-cocycle just means (1), I'm not sure where do your first terms in (2) come from.

Comment: And in any case, if you assume nothing except bilinearity of $\eta$, the Jacobi formula yields a trilinear form in $(a,b,c)$. So you certainly don't get any terms such as $\eta(a,b)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action of $\mathfrak g$ on $\mathbb C$ is supposed to be trivial. You have forgotten this action in the "non zero terms"

$-c\cdot\eta(a,b)-a\cdot\eta(b,c)-b\cdot\eta(a,c)=0$ since $c\cdot\eta(a,b)=a\cdot\eta(b,c)=b\cdot\eta(a,c)=0$

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology#Chevalley-Eilenberg_complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology#Chevalley%E2%80%93Eilenberg_complex)

Comment: Ah, your answer makes me understand  the error of the OP (confusing trivial action in group sense and in Lie algebra sense), apparently also made in Daniel's answer. The point is indeed that $a\cdot\eta(b,c)$ is equal to 0, not to $\eta(b,c)$, etc.

Comment: @YCor not sure if I understand what you mean by *confusing trivial action in group sense and in Lie algebra sense*. I edited the question to include an explicit expansion of the Jacobi identity for the modified bracket $\widetilde{[a,b]}$. Still, the results I get are not the same as $(1)$.

Comment: @AndyMiles your computation of $d\eta(a,b,c)$ is still erroneous, because, for instance, you compute $c\cdot\eta(a,b)$ to be $\eta(a,b)$, while it's zero instead.

Comment: @YCor I see, *$\mathfrak g$ acts trivial on $\mathbb C$* means $c\cdot\eta(a,b)=0$, and not $c\cdot\eta(a,b)=\eta(a,b)$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I say in my first comment...

Comment: @YCor But if $a\cdot c=0$ for all $a\in\mathfrak g$ and $c\in\mathbb C$, then why do we need the first term on the r.h.s. in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology#Chevalley-Eilenberg_complex) equation? After all, $f(x_1,\dots ,x_n)\in\mathbb C$, so the first term should vanish always.

Comment: I can't say more. If you compute correctly, you get correct results.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Write down the Jacobi identity for your modified bracket. You'll see that in fact you also get your $(*)$ term.

Comment: Thank you, I just did that, see my edit to the question. Any idea why I get $\eta(a,\eta(b,c))$ terms instead of the $\eta(a,b)$ terms in $(*)$?

Comment: @AndyMiles I really don't think $k^2 = k$. Instead you should have that the bracket of any element with an element of your copy of $\mathbb{C}$ is zero (so that $\mathbb{C}$ is part of the center, hence the name *central* extension), so that the additional term vanishes.

Comment: I agree that the modified bracket $\widetilde{[a,k]}$ of any element with an element of $\mathbb C$ *should* vanish. But we don't know a priori that it does. We have to prove that, don't we? Regarding $k^2=k$: $k$ is defined as the "base vector" of $\mathbb C$ in $\mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathbb C$, so I thought $k$ behaves algebraically like $1\in\mathbb C$, so $k^2=1^2=1=k$. Wrong?

Comment: @AndyMiles I think it's wrong. First of all, you are looking at $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over itself, so you are "forgetting" the multiplicative structure and $k^2$ isn't even defined. Secondarily, I really think that you ask for those brackets to be zero *a priori*.